# Sql Count(*) from multiple tables but intersection should come

Tags: sql, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-mvc

```
Select distinct(job_id) from A where condition
Select distinct(job_id) from B where condition
Select distinct(job_id) from C where condition
```

Here may be 1,2 and 3 have some common jobId
What I need is count of all job_id which may not get repeated.

Comment: Please add sample data and desired output. The question as written is extremely vague and not comprehensible.

Answer (score 0):

With UNION ?

```
Select job_id from A where condition
UNION
Select job_id from B where condition
UNION
Select job_id from C where condition
```

Comment: How do you separate duplicates?

Comment: I must not have understood the problem well, it would be nice to have an example of input data and the expected result

Comment: this looks fine, UNION eliminates duplicate values. So just use WITH and SELECT COUNT(*) FROM data as in answear below or directy use subquery as a table

Comment: @Boorsuk true! My bad, I always forget the union *all* part :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe `EXCEPT` is what you might be looking for here which provides a disjoint result set across multiple queries. This could probably be handled with `JOIN` logic also but it's a little hard to tell with the limited detail in the question.

[Here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-select.html#SQL-EXCEPT) is the Postgres documentation on the `EXCEPT` keyword.

```
WITH data AS
(
    SELECT job_id FROM A WHERE condition
    EXCEPT
    SELECT job_id FROM B WHERE condition
    EXCEPT
    SELECT job_id FROM C WHERE condition
)
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM data;
```

---

Here is a solution that works but is not scalable. I'm hesitant to post it because I feel like it's ugly and there must be a better way but maybe this will point you in the right direction.

```
WITH a_b_dups AS
(
  SELECT job_id FROM a
  INTERSECT
  SELECT job_id FROM b
), b_c_dups AS
(
  SELECT job_id FROM b
  INTERSECT
  SELECT job_id FROM c
), a_c_dups AS
(
  SELECT job_id FROM a
  INTERSECT
  SELECT job_id FROM c
), dups AS
(
  SELECT job_id FROM a_b_dups
   UNION
  SELECT job_id FROM b_c_dups
   UNION
  SELECT job_id FROM a_c_dups
), uniques AS
(
  SELECT job_id FROM a
   UNION
  SELECT job_id FROM b
   UNION
  SELECT job_id FROM c
  EXCEPT
  SELECT job_id FROM dups
)
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM uniques;
```

[DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/t18RhgRd) to show a working example.

Comment: What if you have a job_id in table B that is not in table A?

Comment: Good point but with more detail from the op a better solution could be provided.